# Cordova & SQLite - All row items returning as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, undefined

I am building an Android application using the Cordova framework within Netbeans IDE. 
I have built a small database with only a few tables and have been able to insert data to the tables, however, I'm finding it hard to retrieve the data.

Every time I query my database, all the items are returning as undefined. The data is inserting fine because the row count increases every time I add a new row and call this:

```
var len = results.rows.length;
alert(len);
```

Here is my code:

```
function readRecord(){
    var db = window.openDatabase("dbResults", "1.0", "Results DB", 1000000);
     db.transaction(getRecord, errorCB);
}

function getRecord(tx){
    try
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT [time], bglevel FROM RECORDS', [], recordSuccess, errorCB);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
function recordSuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    alert(len);
    var res = '';
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        try
        {
            alert("Row = " + i.toString() + " Time =  " + results.rows.item(i).time);
            alert("Row = " + i.toString() + " BG =  " + results.rows.item(i).bglevel);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err.message);
        }
        res = res + '(' +  results.rows.item(i).time + '|' + results.rows.item(i).bglevel + '),';
        alert(res);
    }     
}
```

When I run this, the final alert just has the following text:

```
(undefined,undefined),
(undefined,undefined),
(undefined,undefined),
(undefined,undefined),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am thinking you don't want to do `i.toString` as it will literally convert `i` to a string, which may be breaking things.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't make any difference. i is just the counter for the loop. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: @MaryPoppins i am facing the same issue? did you found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

you need to pass through the rows, not the items, something like:

alert("Row = " + i.toString() + " Time =  " + results.rows[i].item.time);

Answer (score -1):

Inside the index.js make a variable as var db;
this db is more like a global variable whose value persists all throug out the application.

Now in the onDeviceReady() initialize your DB.

```
  var db;
    var app={
    initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            document.addEventListener("pause", function(){ console.log("--- paused ---"); isAppPaused = true;}, false);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
              if(window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) {
                console.log('opening sqlite DB ');
                db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("ECM_MOBILE");
            } else {
                console.log('opening Web SQL DB ');
                db = window.openDatabase("ECM_MOBILE", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            }   
       this.doSomething(db);         
        },
    doSomething:function(db){

    }
  };
app.initialize();
```

Here is an example of executing any sql statement , the database here is your db , the sql is the sql statement passed as string and callback function .

```
read: function(database, sql, callback){
    this.callback = callback;
    this.sql = sql;
    database.transaction(
      function(tx){
          app.doRead(tx);
      }, 
        function(error){
          app.onError(error);
        }
    );  
  },
 onError: function(error){
    console.log("error call back : " + JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log(error);
   },
 onResult: function(tx, result){
    console.log("result call back : " + result);
    this.callback(null, result);
  },
doRead: function(tx){
    console.log("execute sql : " + this.sql);
    tx.executeSql(this.sql , [], 
        function(tx, result){
          app.onResult(tx, result);
        }, 
        function(error){
          app.onError(error);
        }
    );    
  }
```

Hope it helps, you need to integrate it accordingly to check for solution , 
also try `JSON.Stringify(result)`; on the result returned back and `console.log()` it .

Hope it helps.